# ¿Porqué no me muestra el contenido de la API?

Tags: api, fetch, response

Estoy tratando de obtener la temperatura de una ciudad a través de la API de [Weatherbit.io](https://www.weatherbit.io/). Sin embargo, cuando trato de acceder a la propiedad `temp` que esta dentro de `data` él mismo me devuelve `undefined`:

```js
fetch('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?&city_id=3435910&NC&key=d94770c446f94619814c1f4ef3c34fcf')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {

    let clima = document.getElementById('clima');
    console.log(data);
    clima.innerHTML = `Temperatura Actual: ${data.temp}`;

  });
```

```html
<div id="clima"></div>
```

Comment: Qué intentas hacer con `method: 'GET'
    body: JSON.stringify(clima)` dentro de la propia respuesta?? Imagino que has pegado mal el código? Porque eso debería ir en la llamada del fetch, no en la parte donde recibes la respuesta

Comment: Recuerda que la llave de tu API (api key) es secreta y no deberías compartirla (está en la url).

Comment: 1. si haciendo pruebas me quedo pegado ya lo quite gracias!,  2. como recomendas que lo haga lo meta en una const? y lo pase por nombre de la misma decis?, gracias por el aporte!

Answer (score 1):

La cuestión es que:

1. Los datos globales  vienen en una propiedad llamada `data`,
2. Y organizados como un array dentro de dicha propiedad

Entonces tienes que entrar en la propiedad `data` y luego buscar en el índice `0` del array y luego buscar el valor de la propiedad `temp`, algo así:

```
data.data[0].temp
```

Puede que como el parámetro se llama `data` y la propiedad también, te hayas confundido :).

```js
fetch('https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?&city_id=3435910&NC&key=d94770c446f94619814c1f4ef3c34fcf')
    .then(response => response.json())


.then(data => {

    let clima = document.getElementById('clima');
    //method: 'GET'
    //body: JSON.stringify(clima)


    clima.innerHTML = `
    Temperatura Actual: ${data.data[0].temp}
    `;



})
```

```html
<div id="clima"></div>
```

Comment: gracias!! lo resolvi! Sdos.

Comment: Si la respuesta de A. Cedano te ayudó, por favor marcala como aceptada.